# change picture size in slideshow in CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, slideshow, photo

I am currently making a website and when I view the slideshow its too big is there any way of changing the size of it? I am using HTML and CSS made in visual studio and here is an image of the site 50% zoomed out [slideshow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIt6G.jpg)

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-opacity-off", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " w3-opacity-off";
}
```

```css
.mySlides {
  display: none
}

.demo {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="w3-content" style="max-width:1200px">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/09/07/17/50/fruit-3661159_960_720.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/11/12/37/piano-keys-1731467_960_720.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/14/18/31/mushroom-2949539_960_720.jpg" style="width:100%">

    <div class="w3-row-padding w3-section">
      <div class="w3-col s4">
        <img class="demo w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/09/07/17/50/fruit-3661159_960_720.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentDiv(1)">
      </div>
      <div class="w3-col s4">
        <img class="demo w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/11/12/37/piano-keys-1731467_960_720.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentDiv(2)">
      </div>
      <div class="w3-col s4">
        <img class="demo w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/14/18/31/mushroom-2949539_960_720.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentDiv(3)">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You're going to have to give more details. What are you using to make the website and slideshow? What do you mean by 'too big', and what did you want? Are you able to include samples of your html/javascript/whatever, or screenshots of the issue you're having?

Comment: Post the code of this so called slideshow.

Comment: website download is not the way to go. we are the ones helping you, you could at least provide us an online verifiable minimal example so we can at least see what slideshow lib you are using. (jsfiddle, codepen, stackoverflow built in code editor ...)

Comment: I've removed your Google Drive link, fyi and just included your code in an edit. Its a good idea to use JSFiddle, CodePen, or the native snippets here for sampling. Google Drive is a bit frowned upon because it can be used to dox you.

Comment: @32bitlink How big is "too big"? You can adapt the size of images using css , but the css would depend on how big/small you want it to be..

Comment: @Rachel Gallen its too big because you have to scroll down to choose the next image

Answer (score 0):

Looking for something like this? I dropped the W3.css Library. This example is on [W3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow_gallery.asp). From my current location I cannot access the photos you posted so I had to use different example photos.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Position the image container (needed to position the left and right arrows) */

.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Hide the images by default */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}


/* Add a pointer when hovering over the thumbnail images */

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Six columns side by side */

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 1%;
}


/* Add a transparency effect for thumnbail images */

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<h2 style="text-align:center">Slideshow Gallery</h2>

<div class="container" >
  <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_woods_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_5terre_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_woods.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="The Woods">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_5terre.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Cinque Terre">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a fixed height /width for your images however you risk the images becoming skewed. I set a fixed height below, and the images will display within the window, and the thumbs will all be of the same height, however you'd be better off starting with images that are of similar dimensions and using % or vertical height (vh) to size the images smaller as appropriate to what you want.

Hope this helps

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-opacity-off", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " w3-opacity-off";
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  width:900px;
  max-height:100%;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

.w3-content {
  max-width:600px;
  max-height: 50vh!important;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  width: 100%; 
  height:450px;
}

.demo {
  cursor: pointer;
  height:150px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="w3-content">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/09/07/17/50/fruit-3661159_960_720.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/11/12/37/piano-keys-1731467_960_720.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/14/18/31/mushroom-2949539_960_720.jpg">

    <div class="w3-row-padding w3-section">
      <div class="w3-col s4">
        <img class="demo w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/09/07/17/50/fruit-3661159_960_720.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentDiv(1)">
      </div>
      <div class="w3-col s4">
        <img class="demo w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/11/12/37/piano-keys-1731467_960_720.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentDiv(2)">
      </div>
      <div class="w3-col s4">
        <img class="demo w3-opacity w3-hover-opacity-off" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/11/14/18/31/mushroom-2949539_960_720.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentDiv(3)">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```